# Do different Amiibos of the same character unlock different skins?

Tags: amiibo, yoshis-woolly-world

Yoshi's Wooly World has support for Amiibos, beyond the ones directly associated with the game itself - it unlocks special skin patterns based on the character ([there are details here](http://www.techtimes.com/articles/55809/20150527/cute-amiibo-costumes-coming-to-cute-yoshis-woolly-world-game-nintendo.htm)).

If you scan, say, the Mario Party Mario Amiibo and also the Smash Bros Mario Amiibo, do you get two different skins?  Or is there one Mario pattern, that any/either of the Mario Amiibos unlock?

Comment: Based on amiibo behaviour in other games, I'd say it's the character that counts, not the amiibo-series -- mario is mario. I may be wrong, as my testcase was smash-series bowser used in mario party 10 :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you have two different versions of the same character, you still wind up with only one Yoshi.  I bought a Mario Party Bowser and also a Smash Bros Bowser.  It did not create a second Yoshi when I scanned the SB Bowser.

Update: I scanned one of the silver Mario Amiibos, and it still gave me the same red-and-blue Mario skin.  So those ones don't have different skins either.

Comment: Note that I don't have the Gold or Silver Marios to test - I could see those as maybe having different skins, since the entire point of them is that they look different.